# Where is the complete Shambhu Utkarsha Stotra (शम्भूत्कर्ष स्तोत्र) found? (also known as शिवोत्कर्ष स्तोत्र / Shivotkarsha Stotra )

Tags: scripture, shiva, puranas, stotra, vyasa

Sri Shivendra Saraswati has written a bhasya on Shiva Sahasranama stotra ([available here](https://archive.org/details/ionj_shiva-sahstranam-stotra-with-bhashya-of-shivendra-sarasvati-by-shrikrishna-pant-/page/n51/mode/2up)). While explaining the very first name "ParaDeva", he gives an entire stotra composed by Vyasa as "Shivotkarsha Stotra (शिवोत्कर्ष स्तोत्र)". He says this stotra was sung by Vyasa when his hands were paralyzed by Nandi. This event is found in Skandha Purana which is [discussed here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/48841/when-and-why-did-lord-shiva-punish-vedavyasa/48845#48845) also. Here Vyasa just sings the Ashtakam (eight verses). But here in the stotra [quoted in the Bhasya](https://archive.org/details/ionj_shiva-sahstranam-stotra-with-bhashya-of-shivendra-sarasvati-by-shrikrishna-pant-/page/n51/mode/2up), it contains 26 Shlokas. When we analyze the stotra, both seem to be referring to the same event. They both start with:

> एको रुद्रो न द्वितीयो... 
> Rudra is one without second...

The Skandha Purana Ashtakam sung covers events like:

- Lord Shiva drinking Kalakuta
- Tripura Samhara
- Kamadeva Dahana

The Shivotkarsha stotra quoted covers all the above events with verses similar to this with the addition of other events like:

> ... 
> ध्वस्तो यज्ञो दक्षमूर्धा च कृत्तः (You destroyed the Yajna and beheaded Daksha) 
> यत्कोपांशादुत्थितो वीरभद्रः (From the portion of your anger Virabhadra arose) ... 
> ...

The stotra also calls itself as "Shambhu Utkarsha Stotra":

> सर्वं शम्भूत्कर्षपाठेन सिद्धयेत्। 
> Everything is attained by reading of this Shambhu Utkarsha Stotra

It contains Phalashruti also mentioning this stotra giving Punya equal to Rajasuya and also prosperity and Sayujya with Isha:

> राजसूयात्तपुण्यः प्राप्तश्रीरीशसायुज्यमेति ... 
> .. Punya equal to Rajasuya is obtained, Prosperity (Shree) and Sayujya on Isha is also obtained ...

So, where is this complete Shambhu Utkarsha Stotram found? The commentator mentions "48th chapter of Kalika Khanda" in the beginning also, but which scripture is this Kalika Khanda, is it part of some Purana or some other Samhita?

It would be better if someone can post the entire Shambhutkarsha stotra here (and where it is found) along with translation also (Hindi or English).

Comment: bro you came online can you help me regarding this https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/13900/27623